# Object variable or With block variable not set error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework

I'm writing in ASP.NET 4 / VB.NET. I am querying an MSSQL database and sometimes have records come back with no results...so I enclosed the call I was making upon the results in an If..Else clause to set a default value if the database comes back with no results...but now I am getting this "Object variable or With block variable not set error". Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim clcfirst
Dim rhcfirst
Dim clcdate As Date
Dim rhcdate As Date
If IsNothing(clcexists) Then
   clcfirst = Date.Now.Subtract(year)
   rhcfirst = Date.Now.Subtract(year)
   clcdate = clcfirst
   rhcdate = rhcfirst
Else
   clcfirst = clcexists.FirstOrDefault()
   rhcfirst = rhcexists.FirstOrDefault()
   clcdate = clcfirst.SignatureDate
   rhcdate = rhcfirst.SignatureDate
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is the DateTime year variable being set? Could that be null?

If you want to subtract a year, you could just do:

```
 clcdate = Date.Now.AddYears(-1)
 rhcdate = Date.Now.AddYears(-1)
```